# Remove some rows from table according to users specified

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data consists of 1024 rows and 2 columns.
I want to remove some rows of the table.
If you provide the starting numeric value and ending numeric value of the first column, the intervals of the starting value, ending value and the values in between them  of the rows are to be deleted.
Is it possible in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the question?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: My data consists of 1024 rows and 2 columns, my intend is to delete rows based on column values which are within a certain range(starting numeric value and ending numeric value). multiple column range intervals are selected from one table

Comment: 3 interval values should be provided at the same time, values are displayed based on three intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intent is to delete rows based on column values which are within a certain range (*starting numberic value and ending numeric value*), then you can use `BETWEEN` operator

```
DELETE FROM tab
WHERE  col1 BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Comment: My intend is to select rows based on column values which are within a certain range, 3 intervals(starting and ending numeric value) can be selected from the table.